# jQuery - Get value from JSON Stringify

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a form, that I need to get the values from:

```
var formConfig = JSON.stringify($("#bookingform").serializeArray());
```

which returns below:

```
[{"name":"client_id","value":"1"},{"name":"consignee_id","value":""},{"name":"client","value":"DAKO"},{"name":"model","value":"2"},{"name":"type","value":"2"},{"name":"temperatur","value":"2"},{"name":"shipper_labels","value":"1"},{"name":"batteri_labels","value":"1"},{"name":"batteri_number","value":"2222"},{"name":"pickup","value":"April 27, 2017 18:25"},{"name":"intern_marks","value":"fdsfads"},{"name":"extern_marks","value":"sadsfdsf"},{"name":"consignee","value":""},{"name":"marks","value":""}]
```

I then need to access above values from the JSON string, which I am using this function to:

```
var confirmBooking = function(element, setting, correct, notcorrect) {
    $('.confirm-booking')
    .find(element)
    .html(setting === 1 ? correct : notcorrect);
};
```

The thought is, I can use above function:

```
confirmBooking('.config_batteri', formConfig.client_id, "Yes", "No");
```

and so on..

`formConfig.client_id` should return `1`, since that's the value in the JSON string above.

However it returns `undefined`:

```
console.log(formConfig.client_id); // Returns "undefined"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `JSON.parse()`, to make it a regular JavaScript object again.

What `JSON.stringify()` does is, as the name implies, make it a string. That is just a regular string, that represents JSON data. It doesn't magically have the JSON data properties.

Furthermore `serializeArray()` returns an array of `{name: ..., value: ...}` objects. If you didn't turn it into a JSON string, the result still could not easily be accessed by doing `formConfig.client_id`. You'd have to loop through the `formConfig` array, to find the desired name/value pair.

From the looks of it, you don't need to turn the JavaScript object into JSON at all, if you are just going to use it in the same script (unless you are going to send the JSON string somewhere else perhaps).

---

Based on OP's comments, I'm assuming OP just want to access a particular form element's value. Using jQuery, this can easily be accomplished with:

```
// get the value of the client_id element (assuming it's an input element)
var client_id = $( '#bookingform input[name="client_id"]' ).val();
// call the function
confirmBooking( '.config_batteri', client_id, "Yes", "No" );
```

If you want to have an object with all the form values, have a look at the answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-javascript-object-with-jquery).

Comment: So, first JSON.stringify the data from the form, and then use JSON.parse()? Would you mind including an example? I still get undefined.

Comment: After edit: correct, I don't need to send the data elsewhere. I just want to create an "easy" way to access all the data in my form, and use it. Is there a better way of achieving that?

Comment: @oliverbj Ah okay, I see. Yes I'll expand my answer to give you an example

Comment: Thanks a lot! Really means a lot

Comment: @oliverbj I've added a simple example of how you can access a single form value at a time (assuming it's unique `<input>` elements). For more complex operations I've linked to a relevant question.

Answer (score 1):

I think that's what you want.

```
console.log(formConfig.confirmBooking);
```

Comment: No, I want to access the data from the "JSON" string.

Comment: console.log(formConfig[0].name);

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
var jsonStr = '[{"name":"client_id","value":"1"},
                {"name":"consignee_id","value":""},
                {"name":"client","value":"DAKO"},
                {"name":"model","value":"2"},
                {"name":"type","value":"2"},
                {"name":"temperatur","value":"2"},
                {"name":"shipper_labels","value":"1"},
                {"name":"batteri_labels","value":"1"},
                {"name":"batteri_number","value":"2222"},
                {"name":"pickup","value":"April 27, 2017 18:25"},
                {"name":"intern_marks","value":"fdsfads"},
                {"name":"extern_marks","value":"sadsfdsf"},
                {"name":"consignee","value":""},
                {"name":"marks","value":""}]';

var obj = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
var val = obj[0].value;
```

The reason you can't do `obj[0].name` is because your parsed JSON object has a collection of objects, where the first object has this structure:

```
{
    name:"client_id",
    value:"1"
}
```

So, you have to access it using `obj[0].value` **NOT** `obj[0].name` as it would give you `client_id`.

Answer (score 0):

would change of syntax help? please try

```
console.log(formConfig[0]['client_id']);
```

I hope it works for you

Comment: Sorry, that still returns undefined.

Comment: apologies, I wonder if changing array position helps, if no then Decent Dabbler appraoch is best-  console.log(formConfig[1]['client_id']);

Answer (score 0):

[image: TestingLocally]

Since it's an array of objects, you target the first element which returns an object and then use the "value" property to get the actual value of `1` which you expected .

Also use `parseInt("1")` to get `1` as a type `"number"`

Hope this solves the issue ! Let me no ASAP

== EDIT

```
var formConfig = [{
    "name": "client_id",
    "value": "1"
}, {
    "name": "consignee_id",
    "value": ""
}, {
    "name": "client",
    "value": "DAKO"
}];

// This function returns the value for the name
function search(str) {

    for (var obj of formConfig) {
        if (obj.name == str) {
            return obj.value;
        }
    }
}

search("client_id"); // 1
search("client"); // DAKO
```

Comment: Would it be possible to make it so I wouldn't have to use formConfig[**number**].value ? But instead, use formConfig[**name**] ?