# How to read the value from Json Stringify in my case?

Tags: jquery, json, stringify

After I validate user login, if it failed it will show the following error message

**jquery**

```
console.log('Full error  = ' + JSON.stringify(showError));
console.log('test 1 =' + showError.responseText);
```

**Error message**

```
Full error  = {"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\"error\":\"invalid_grant\",\"error_description\":\"The user name or password is incorrect.\"}","responseJSON":{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"The user name or password is incorrect."},"status":400,"statusText":"Bad Request"}


test 1 ={"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"The user name or password is incorrect."}
```

I want to display only `The user name or password is incorrect` message only

I already check this [jQuery - Get value from JSON Stringify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43570670/jquery-get-value-from-json-stringify) link

Comment: can you try console.log(showError.responseText.error_description);

Comment: @Satya I already tried brother, it's `undefined`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to parse the `responseText` property since it's a JSON string.

```
console.log(JSON.parse(showError.responseText).error_description);

// or using bracket notation
console.log(JSON.parse(showError.responseText)['error_description']);
```

```js
var showError = {"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\"error\":\"invalid_grant\",\"error_description\":\"The user name or password is incorrect.\"}","responseJSON":{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"The user name or password is incorrect."},"status":400,"statusText":"Bad Request"} ;

console.log(JSON.parse(showError.responseText).error_description);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use JSON.parse method to parse a json data in string format.It will return a json object.In your case.

```
var response = JSON.stringify('{"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\"error\":\"invalid_grant\",\"error_description\":\"The user name or password is incorrect.\"}","responseJSON":{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"The user name or password is incorrect."},"status":400,"statusText":"Bad Request"}
')
var error_message = response.responseText.error_description
```

**error_message** variable contains your error message