# How to read my complex JSON Stringify data in JQuery?

Tags: jquery, json, jsonparser

I am trying to display the message **Email 'xxx@gmail.com' is already taken**
from this JSON

```
{"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\"Message\":\"The request is invalid.\",\"ModelState\":{\"\":[\"Name xxx is already taken.\",\"Email 'xxx@gmail.com' is already taken.\"]}}","responseJSON":{"Message":"The request is invalid.","ModelState":{"":["Name xxx is already taken.","Email 'xxx@gmail.com' is already taken."]}},"status":400,"statusText":"Bad Request"}
```

I already checked with my previous question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55090672/how-to-read-the-value-from-json-stringify-in-my-case/55090709#55090709). I tried the same and different kind also like below. But I failed

```
fail(function (showError) {
        console.log('Signup failed');
        console.log('full error = ' + JSON.stringify(showError));
        var response = JSON.stringify(showError);
        console.log("response error = "+JSON.stringify(response.responseText.ModelState));

        console.log('Message error = ' + JSON.parse(showError.responseText).Message);
        console.log('ModelState error = ' + JSON.parse(showError.responseText).ModelState[0]);
        //console.log('ModelState error val= ' + JSON.parse(showError.responseText).ModelState[0].val);
        console.log('ModelState error text= ' + JSON.parse(showError.responseText).ModelState[0].text);
    });
```

Comment: Not even sure if the `responseText` is valid, but chrome parses it. `ModelState` is an object with an empty string for the key - so `JSON.parse(showError.responseText).ModelState[""][0]`

Comment: @tymeJV yes, It's working. please make it in answer. I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ModelState` is an object with an empty string as the first key (which contains your array of errors) - so you can do:

```
let errors = JSON.parse(showError.responseText).ModelState[""];
```